# Why isn't this regexp working

Tags: python, regex

I have a source code of a webpage formatted like this:

```
<span class="l r positive-icon">
Turkish
</span>
<span>
The.Mist[2007]DvDrip[Eng]-aXXo
</span>
<span class="l r neutral-icon">
Vietnamese
</span>
<span>
The.Mist.2007.720p.Bluray.x264.YIFY 
</span>
```

As you can see, there are either spans with the class of **"l r positive-icon"** or **"l r neutral-icon"**. I want to get only the languages, so everything between the span with any class. I use this regexp but it gives me an empty list:

```
allLanguages = re.findall('<span class=".*">\s(.*)\s</span>', allLanguagesTags)
```

allLanguagesTags contains the source code shown above. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: Why not use an actual HTML parser to parse this? Trying to extract info from HTML with regular expressions is known to [cause some issues](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348).

Comment: Works for me:  I get ['Turkish', 'Vietnamese']

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am using BeautifulSoup to get all the <td>s with the class of "a1", but I don't know how to extract the content from within the tags with BeautifulSoup, so I'm using regular expressions.

Comment: @user3647430: why didn't you ask about that in the first place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't realise I could do that with BeautifulSoup. Thanks for your answer, I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions. Use an actual HTML parser. I recommend you use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(yourhtml)
languages = [s.get_text().strip() for s in soup.find_all('span', class_=True)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <span class="l r positive-icon">
... Turkish
... </span>
... <span>
... The.Mist[2007]DvDrip[Eng]-aXXo
... </span>
... <span class="l r neutral-icon">
... Vietnamese
... </span>
... <span>
... The.Mist.2007.720p.Bluray.x264.YIFY 
... </span>
... ''')
>>> [s.get_text().strip() for s in soup.find_all('span', class_=True)]
[u'Turkish', u'Vietnamese']
```

Comment: Love that soup of yours, Martijn. +1 :)